# $S_3$ is indecomposable but not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

My argument goes like this:

$S_3$ is not simple as $A_3$ is a subgroup of index $2$. On the other hand, if $S_3$ is decomposable, then $S_3 = A \times B$, where $|A| = 2$ and $|B| = 3$. But in this case $A = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}_3$, in which case its product is the cyclic group of order $6$; contradiction.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that argument is fine.

Comment: One can explicitly say that $A_3$ is a nontrivial *normal* subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your argument is right! As there are only two groups of order 6 (up to isomorphism) one is $\Bbb{Z}_6$ which is cyclic and other is $S_3$ which is non-abelian and can not be written as direct product of two of it's proper subgroup otherwise $S_3$ will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_6$ !

Comment: I'd say this is a worse answer than the one given in the OP, as it assumes more. (For example that we've already classified the groups of order $6$.)

Comment: I'm not answering the question but supporting his point of view, by motivating him to think about the classification of groups of different orders. Before judging someone you need to judge intension of that person, as good is bad in bad world.